# System freeze while starting a Vagrant box via VirtualBox on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: virtualbox, encryption, 15.04, vagrant

I'm starting a virtual machine with:

```
vagrant up
```

The provider is VirtualBox.

After few seconds the system freezes and I can't do anything. Only a hard reset is possible.

Unfortunately I can't see anything suspicious in the logs:

```
...
00:00:00.143578 ******************** End of CPUID dump **********************
00:00:00.145703 VM: Halt method global1 (5)
00:00:00.145710 HaltedGlobal1 config: cNsSpinBlockThresholdCfg=2000
00:00:00.145714 Changing the VM state from 'CREATING' to 'CREATED'.
00:00:00.146015 SharedFolders host service: adding host mapping
00:00:00.146020     Host path '/home/user_name/project_name/devbox', map name 'vagrant', writable, automount=false, create_symlinks=true, missing=false
00:00:00.146097 Changing the VM state from 'CREATED' to 'POWERING_ON'.
00:00:00.146710 NAT: set redirect TCP host 127.0.0.1:2222 => guest 10.0.2.15:22
00:00:00.146806 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_ON' to 'RUNNING'.
00:00:00.148732 Guest Log: BIOS: VirtualBox 4.3.26
00:00:00.148818 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:00.157868 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={480b372c-c0b5-4c23-9bd7-dcbb85b1594c} aComponent={Display} aText={Could not take a screenshot (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false
00:00:00.168034 Display::handleDisplayResize(): uScreenId = 0, pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0, flags=0x1
00:00:00.174891 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:00.174953 AHCI#0: Port 0 reset
00:00:00.175519 Guest Log: BIOS: AHCI 0-P#0: PCHS=16383/16/63 LCHS=1024/255/63 83886080 sectors
00:00:00.175577 PIT: mode=2 count=0x48d3 (18643) - 64.00 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:00.190899 Display::handleDisplayResize(): uScreenId = 0, pvVRAM=00007fa8d5937000 w=640 h=480 bpp=32 cbLine=0xA00, flags=0x1
00:00:00.537461 NAT: old socket rcv size: 128KB
00:00:00.537476 NAT: old socket snd size: 128KB
00:00:02.648091 Display::handleDisplayResize(): uScreenId = 0, pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0, flags=0x1
00:00:02.650582 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:02.650757 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=1, bootseq=0002
00:00:02.651025 Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from Hard Disk...
00:00:03.091510 PIT: mode=2 count=0x12a5 (4773) - 249.98 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:03.408419 PIT: mode=0 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:03.709126 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:03.728571 AHCI#0: Port 0 reset
00:00:06.861887 Guest Additions information report: Version 4.3.10 r93012 '4.3.10_Ubuntu'
00:00:06.861928 Guest Additions information report: Interface = 0x00010004 osType = 0x00053100 (64-bit)
00:00:06.861974 Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x0) seamless: no, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
00:00:06.862019 Guest reported fixed hypervisor window at 00000c00000 (size = 0x800000, rc = VINF_SUCCESS)
00:00:06.881410 Guest Log: vboxguest: major 0, IRQ 20, I/O port d020, MMIO at 00000000f0400000 (size 0x400000)
00:00:08.425021 NAT: IPv6 not supported
00:00:08.443541 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:00:08.445786 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:00:09.070544 NAT: link up
```

How can I debug this issue?

System stats:

```
$ uname -a
Linux user-Inspiron-7548 3.19.0-16-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 30 16:09:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

I use disk encryption.

**Update**:

- 2015.05.13 - this issue doesn't appear when I use a 32 bit VM

  ```
  mkdir vagrant_32; cd vagrant_32
  vagrant init -m hashicorp/precise32
  vagrant up
  # works fine
  ```

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I ended up switching to an older Kernel I was using on 14.10 which I think has resolved my issue. The one I am using now is: `3.17.6-031706-generic`.

Comment: Does this kernel (3.17.6-031706-generic) work with 15.04?

Comment: It's still booting my VM (it's a complex chef setup) but it's got past the bit that was hanging at the start. I think it was to do with host only networking. 

I had it installed before when I was on 14.10. Perhaps you could try the 4.0 kernel  as that is stable and can be used now apparently though.

Comment: Did you have any success with this?

Comment: i can  confirm: the 32bit boxes work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve this issue by updating to VirtualBox **5.0**.

I removed my old VirtualBox **4.3**, then downloaded 5.0 from [here](http://dlc-cdn.sun.com/virtualbox/5.0.0_BETA3/index.html) (trusty package).

Then I installed **5.0** and I can finally start a **64 bit** VM over the VirtualBox **GUI**!

Unfortunately current Vagrant 1.7.2 doesn't support VirtualBox 5.0 according to [this documentatioin](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox).

I got this error message:

```
$ vagrant status
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

Vagrant has already a fix for that but you need to wait for the next release.

Until then you can follow [this instructions](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5572) to patch it. It's really easy, you just need to edit/create few files in `/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/`

All credits go to the [google vagrant group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/E7nxiPzxQL4).